How to remove duplicates and unify values in lists where values are very close to each other in Python?
I have in Python lists like below:
x1 = ['lock-service',
 'jenkins-service',
 'xyz-reporting-service',
 'ansible-service',
 'harbor-service',
 'version-service',
 'jira-service',
 'kubernetes-service',
 'capo-service',
 'permission-service',
 'artifactory-service',
 'vault-service',
 'harbor-service-prod',
 'rundeck-service',
 'cruise-control-service',
 'artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud',
 'helm-service',
 'Capo Service',
 'rocket-chat-service',
 'reporting-service',
 'bitbucket-service',
 'rocketchat-service']

or
x2 = ['journal-service',
 'lock-service',
 'jenkins-service',
 'xyz-reporting-service',
 'ansible-service',
 'harbor-service',
 'version-service',
 'jira-service',
 'kubernetes-service',
 'capo-service',
 'permission-service',
 'artifactory-service',
 'vault-service',
 'rundeck-service',
 'cruise-control-service',
 'helm-service',
 'database-ticket-service',
 'rocket-chat-service',
 'ansible-dpservice',
 'reporting-service',
 'bitbucket-service',
 'rocketchat-service']

As you can see in both lists, duplicate values appear in different forms, for example:
in the list 1:

'xyz-reporting-service' and 'reporting-service'
'harbor-service' and 'harbor-service-prod'
'capo-service' and 'Capo Service'
'artifactory-service' and 'artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud'
'rocket-chat-service' and 'rocketchat-service'

in the list 2:

'xyz-reporting-service' and 'reporting-service'
'rocket-chat-service' and 'rocketchat-service'
'ansible-service' and 'ansible-dpservice'

I need a universal solution that does not only on these sample lists:

will remove the duplicated sample values presented above
unifies the values in the list to the name-service form

How can I do that in Python 3.11 ?

You want fuzzy matching....

@ScottBoston - could you present sample solution with your idea, please ?

possibly - as@ScottBoston mentioned in the answer - look at this question

Of course, what you're calling "duplicates" are not duplicates. There are similarities so you will have to determine what constitutes a comparison between two values that are so similar that they might be considered to be (effectively) the same thing. Fuzzy matching is likely to be imperfect

Do you have a specific pattern for producing the final output? if so, what don't you use regex for matching contents based on that, then make your items in a set to avoid duplications @dingaro

My solution adds cleanup steps before and after fuzzy matching. Shoutout to @Scott Boston, I learned about variable naming within list comprehension from his answer.
!pip install RapidFuzz


import re
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, utils

def dedup(lst):
    lst = list(set([re.sub(r'-service.*$', r'-service', x) for x in lst])) #clean up values with extra characters after "-service"
    vals = {val1:{val2:ratio for val2 in lst
                  if val1!=val2 #avoid matching to self
                  and (ratio:=fuzz.WRatio(val1, val2, processor=utils.default_process))>=90} #fuzzy match
            for val1 in lst 
            if len(subs:=val1.split('-'))==2 #name-service format requested by OP
            and subs[-1]=='service'} #check if ends in "-service"
    not_captured = [x for x in lst if x not in list(vals.keys())+sum([list(x.keys()) for x in vals.values()], [])] #vals from original list not in match dict keys or values
    new_x = list(vals.keys())+[''.join(x.replace('-service', '').split('-'))+'-service' for x in not_captured] #deduplicated list forcing name-service format for longer values with extra "-"
    return new_x #returns only deduplicated list


dedup(x1)

['jenkins-service',
 'artifactory-service',
 'rocketchat-service',
 'rundeck-service',
 'harbor-service',
 'bitbucket-service',
 'lock-service',
 'reporting-service',
 'permission-service',
 'capo-service',
 'jira-service',
 'version-service',
 'ansible-service',
 'vault-service',
 'helm-service',
 'kubernetes-service',
 'cruisecontrol-service']

dedup(x2)

['jenkins-service',
 'artifactory-service',
 'rocketchat-service',
 'rundeck-service',
 'harbor-service',
 'bitbucket-service',
 'lock-service',
 'reporting-service',
 'permission-service',
 'capo-service',
 'jira-service',
 'version-service',
 'journal-service',
 'ansible-service',
 'vault-service',
 'helm-service',
 'kubernetes-service',
 'cruisecontrol-service',
 'databaseticket-service']


It is called the named expression with walrus operator, := see looks like walrus teeth on the side.

@ScottBoston nice! super convenient

From this post:
!pip install thefuzz

x1 = ['lock-service',
 'jenkins-service',
 'xyz-reporting-service',
 'ansible-service',
 'harbor-service',
 'version-service',
 'jira-service',
 'kubernetes-service',
 'capo-service',
 'permission-service',
 'artifactory-service',
 'vault-service',
 'harbor-service-prod',
 'rundeck-service',
 'cruise-control-service',
 'artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud',
 'helm-service',
 'Capo Service',
 'rocket-chat-service',
 'reporting-service',
 'bitbucket-service',
 'rocketchat-service']

from itertools import combinations
from thefuzz import fuzz

[(ratio, a, b) for a, b in combinations(x1, 2) if (ratio:=fuzz.partial_ratio(a, b)) > 90 ]

Output:
[(91, 'lock-service', 'rundeck-service'),
 (100, 'xyz-reporting-service', 'reporting-service'),
 (100, 'harbor-service', 'harbor-service-prod'),
 (100, 'artifactory-service', 'artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud'),
 (94, 'rocket-chat-service', 'rocketchat-service')]

Added lowercase transformation:
[(ratio, a, b) for a, b in combinations(x1, 2) if (ratio:=fuzz.partial_ratio(a.lower(), b.lower())) > 90 ]

Output:
[(91, 'lock-service', 'rundeck-service'),
 (100, 'xyz-reporting-service', 'reporting-service'),
 (100, 'harbor-service', 'harbor-service-prod'),
 (92, 'capo-service', 'Capo Service'),
 (100, 'artifactory-service', 'artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud'),
 (94, 'rocket-chat-service', 'rocketchat-service')]


It is not exact, that 90 ratio missed the 'capo-service' and 'Capo Service', but then again it is a "fuzzy" match.  Maybe lowercasing both will improve capture.

This may not be a general solution but it works for your sample data.
You will need to:
pip install python-Levenshtein

Then:
from Levenshtein import jaro
from itertools import combinations
import re

x1 = [
    "lock-service",
    "jenkins-service",
    "xyz-reporting-service",
    "ansible-service",
    "harbor-service",
    "version-service",
    "jira-service",
    "kubernetes-service",
    "capo-service",
    "permission-service",
    "artifactory-service",
    "vault-service",
    "harbor-service-prod",
    "rundeck-service",
    "cruise-control-service",
    "artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud",
    "helm-service",
    "Capo Service",
    "rocket-chat-service",
    "reporting-service",
    "bitbucket-service",
    "rocketchat-service",
]

x2 = [
    "journal-service",
    "lock-service",
    "jenkins-service",
    "xyz-reporting-service",
    "ansible-service",
    "harbor-service",
    "version-service",
    "jira-service",
    "kubernetes-service",
    "capo-service",
    "permission-service",
    "artifactory-service",
    "vault-service",
    "rundeck-service",
    "cruise-control-service",
    "helm-service",
    "database-ticket-service",
    "rocket-chat-service",
    "ansible-dpservice",
    "reporting-service",
    "bitbucket-service",
    "rocketchat-service",
]

def normalise(s):
    return re.sub(r"-\s", "", s.lower())

for x in x1, x2:
    for a, b in combinations(x, 2):
        if len(a) > len(b):
            a, b = b, a
        A = normalise(a)
        B = normalise(b)
        if A in B or jaro(A, B) > 0.9:
            print(a, b)
    print()

Output:
reporting-service xyz-reporting-service
harbor-service harbor-service-prod
capo-service Capo Service
artifactory-service artifactory-service.xyz.abc.cloud
rocketchat-service rocket-chat-service

reporting-service xyz-reporting-service
ansible-service ansible-dpservice
rocketchat-service rocket-chat-service

